# Web service call missing field value xamarin IOS

Tags: ios, web-services, xamarin.ios, xamarin

I'm having a web reference which is being used by both a Xamarin IOS application, Xamaring Android application, and a Windows Store application.

And this all worked very well, until I updated Xamarin.

Now, there is a field that  But it works fine for the Android and Windows applications.

I have tried to update the web reference multiple times, with no luck. I have also tried to debug the web service locally, to see if it returns the same , which it does.

When I receive it in my Windows Store app., it looks like this:

[image]

And in my IOS app., it looks like this:

[image]

It is always the `StructureId` that is never set, for some reason. And it was not like that before I updated Xamarin.

Anyone who knows what I am doing wrong, or have stumbled onto the same kind of problem ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to make it work. I am not sure if it cached anything, or what, but it helped to add some "noise" on the webservice call. 
I just added `DateTime.Now.Ticks` to my webservice URL in `Reference.cs`, so it would always be a new URL call:

```
this.Url = "http://somewebsitename.com/ReportService/ReportService.asmx?v=" + DateTime.Now.Ticks;
```

Answer (score 0):

That looks like the linker removed unused members. Defaults have not changed (it's not related to your update) but you should check that your application is being built with **Link SDK** (and not **Link all**).

If you want a smaller executable and set **Link all** to achieve this then you'll need to add `[Preserve]` attributes on the structure you're serializing (e.g. used in web services).

Comment: It is set to `Link SDK assemblies only`, and not `Link All`. And it did not help.
I'm getting the exact same problem with another application now: returns the right number of objects, but the values is either `null` or `0`. But, if I debug it in a simulator on another Mac, it works fine.